# Express-store and payment method - replace Authorize.net option label name

Tags: expresso-store, payment-gateway

How can I replace Authorize.net payment method option name from 'Authorize.net AIM' to 'Credit Card'?

I see situations where customers during the checkout process are confused with that not common for them name of the payment gateway.

Also I'm looking towards name change somewhere in the settings/DB rather than jQuery string replace.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found where it must be changed on the DB level: `exp_store_payment_methods` and a column named `title`